# looping the data using date variable in python

Tags: python, loops, date, pandas

I have the following dataframe with datetime, lon and lat variables. This data is collected for each second which means each date is repeated 60 times

I am doing some calculations using lat, lon values and at the end I need to write 
this data to Postgres table.

```
2016-07-27 06:43:45    50.62    3.15
2016-07-27 06:43:46    50.67    3.22
2016-07-28 07:23:45    52.32    3.34
2016-07-28 07:24:46    52.67    3.45
```

Currently I have 10 million records . It is taking longer time if I use whole dataframe for computing.

How can I loop this for each date, write it to DB and clear the dataframe??

I have converted the datetime variable to date format

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df = df.sort(['datetime'])

my computation is
df.loc[(df['lat'] > 50.10) & (df['lat'] <= 50.62), 'var1'] = 1
df.loc[(df['lan'] > 3.00) & (df['lan'] <= 3.20), 'var2'] = 1
```

Writing it to DB

```
df.to_sql('Table1', engine,if_exists = "replace",index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the `groupby()` function? You can use it to treat each 'date' as a seperate DataFrame and then run your computations.

```
for sub_df in df.groupby('date'):
    # your computations
```